# Puppet file .pp extension name

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

Can someone advise me what is the puppet file **.pp** 
 extension?

As per my knowledge Puppet is a not full name.

Just correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: This is probably not related to programming.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  I don't think it's "What is Puppet", since you're asking *here* and have tagged the question appropriately.  But I don't know how else to interpret "Puppet is not a full name".  Have you had a look at [the Puppet documentation](https://puppet.com/docs)?  It very likely can answer your question.

Comment: I upvoted this question. I think this is related to programming. The .pp files are used for declaring classes in puppet. I added a snippet to currently the only answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51382925/266531 below.

Answer (score 6):

`.pp` files are called manifests in Puppet. This is documented at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_summary.html#files.

> Puppet always begins compiling with the main manifest, which can be
>   either a single file or a directory containing several files. (Some
>   documents also call this the “site manifest.”) See the reference page
>   on the main manifest for details about this special file/directory.
>
> Any classes declared in the main manifest can be autoloaded from
>   manifest files in modules. Puppet will also autoload any classes
>   declared by an optional external node classifier. See the reference
>   page on catalog compilation for details.
>
> The simplest Puppet deployment is a lone main manifest file with a few
>   resources. Complexity can grow progressively, by grouping resources
>   into modules and classifying your nodes more granularly.